# Get the Name of the button created through code on click event

Tags: vb.net, button, dynamic

I am adding buttons through code. So there is a container control and every time the user clicks "Add button", a button gets added to the container control this way:

```
 Dim btnItem As New Button
 btnItem.Text = strName
 btnItem.Name = "btn-" & strName
 AddHandler btnItem.Click, AddressOf f_ViewNameInfo
 ButtonContainer.Controls.Add(btnItem)
```

Problem is inside `f_ViewNameInfo` function, how do I know which button send the command. In this function I want to get the `strName` part of the button's name and then work from that. I tried to give parameters to the function, but then the `AddHandler` part of the above code threw errors, as I am not supposed to give parameters there.

Comment: on the button click event, you can obtain the button that was pressed by looking at the sender object. you would need to cast sender to a Button control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the definition of the `Click` event:

```
Public Event Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
```

Define your function `f_ViewNameInfo` with these two parameters, and the button that raises it can be obtained from the `sender` parameter (you will need to cast it to a button first with `DirectCast(sender, Button)`):

```
Public Sub f_ViewNameInfo(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim str As String = DirectCast(sender, Button).Name
End Function
```

Note that you should add more safety etc around this, such as checking that `sender` really is a button before attempting to cast it.

Comment: Thanks. I added handler function for each button I add and that does it, but I think it has something to do with threads. Is that true? If so, what are the implications, in case I haven't taken care of them?