# Get Button Id Sender In Grid Batch update Dev Express vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I have a method "Grid Batch Update", in this case, i want get an id from button clicked in this method

```
Private Sub grid_BatchUpdate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataBatchUpdateEventArgs) Handles grid.BatchUpdate

      'My Code

End Sub
```

I have tried to search but not found the answer

Comment: `Dim b As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)` then get Id from `b.ID`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the Name of the button created through code on click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804474/get-the-name-of-the-button-created-through-code-on-click-event)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thanks for your answer, but i have try it before and i get an error

Comment: Is this a button in the GV? Get button from sender and then dim gRow as GridViewRow = btn.namingcontainer gets you the GV row

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal my button out of gridview

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then as a general rule, you can use "sender".

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim btn As Button = sender

    Debug.Print("id of button is " & btn.ID)

End Sub
```

However, do note if you going to have say several buttions use the SAME event?

Then you should remove the handles from above. And then you "must" then set the on-click event.

So, above becomes:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender

    Debug.Print("id of button is " & btn.ID)


End Sub
```

And I might then say have two buttons use the same click event. eg this:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
```

So, if you double click on a button from the web forms designer, it will NOT put in a OnClick tag, but uses the "handles button one in code behind.

Either way is fine - but you don't need (nor want) the "handles" tied to one button on the code behind - so use markup OnClick="Button1_Click1"

In above, then clicking on either button would result in this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks before for your answer, but i'm have try it before.. i'm using ASPxGridView DevExpress and event ASPxGridBase.BatchUpdate .. when i'm using `Dim btn As Button = sender` then i get an error : `Unable to cast object of type 'DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridView' to type 'DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxButton'.` .. I have created an inquiry ticket to devexpress, but the process is very long

Comment: That certainly suggests the button is inside of the grid, or perhaps this is a special devexpress button of some type?. You can try dim btn as ASPxButton. So it suggests this is not a asp button but a dev express button. But notice how error msg spit out the button type - so try dim as that button type

Comment: I'm already try it before too, and the same error .. but thanks you for helping me, i will explore again and maybe use another way .. thanks you

Comment: I don't know what that "event" is for in regards to dev-express. But the sender type is of DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridView. So dim gv as DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridView' = sender will work.